# Find unique values in a two dimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a two dimensional array. I would like to find the unique values that are stored in elements (i,1) and output those to a worksheet.

I know how to output to a worksheet. How do I find the unique values?

If possible, I would also like to drop all non alpha-characters before the first alpha-character of the element.

This range is stored in the array:
[image]

What I am trying to produce from the unique elements:
[image]

Comment: I guess you could try using a dictionary

Comment: There's also the built-in "remove duplicates" thing...

Comment: The slow but simple way to strip the non alpha characters is to loop through the characters at the start of each item, until you find one that matches any of the letters ABCDEFG..Z using INSTR. I would initially pass the whole column through to the VBA function and return a column of cleaned results, which you can then wrap in the new Excel function UNIQUE to get the unique values
ie like =UNIQUE(MyAlphaStripper(A1:A500))

Comment: I will give these solutions a try and report back.